# Scale along curve not working (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, transforms, instances

I started a thread yesterday as I was having some trouble with a GN graph that i was working through from a youtube video.  The creator of the video was kinda enough to answer my question on youtube, so that sorted out the first issue.

However, I've now run into another issue with the same setup, and Im not sure I'll get an answer this time.

As I said in my other thread, im very new to Blender and GN, so im trying with my limited knowledge to get this to work, but im not having any luke.

The issue here is that, probably because this setup is a bit unconvential (as the creator stated at the start of the video, and at least based on all the other examples i looked at as far as how to move instances along multiple curves), the convential method of scaling instances on a curve is not working.  I've tried using Capture Attribute to get the curve factor at the beginning of the graph, and plug this into a Scale Instances node down the line, but something about it is not working and sending the data along.  I've tried many different combinations of plugging the nodes in in differnt places, but no luck.

The scaling along the curve is the last part of the puzzle i need to get this setup working.  Im hoping someone on here has some insight into this, why it isnt working, or perhaps how to restructure the initial part of the graph to maintane its functionality, but it a more conventional way.  The multi-curve part of this is key.  If this was operating on a single curve, I would have had it all figured out already.  The current blend file is attached, and is working, aside from the scaling functionality.

Thanks!

[image]